# Changing the color of the animate box

Tags: customization

Is there a way to change the coloring of the boxes that are generated by Animate or Manipulate? The color of what is gray by default.

```
Animate[ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[n, {{1}, 0}, {40, All}]], {n, 0, 
  255, 1}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: To change all panels, use the menu `Mathematica | Preferences ... | Open Option Inspector`; with `Global Preferences` search for `panel`, then select `Formatting Options | Expression Formatting | Controls Options | PanelBoxOptions | Background` and set to desired color.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can wrap `Animate` and `Manipulate` with [`Style`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html) and set the [`DefaultOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultOptions.html) for [`Panel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Panel.html):

```
 Style[#, DefaultOptions -> {Panel -> {Background -> LightBlue}}] & @
   Animate[ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[n, {{1}, 0}, {40, All}]], {n, 0, 255, 1}, 
      AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

```
 Style[#, DefaultOptions -> {Panel -> {Background -> LightBlue}}] & @
   Manipulate[ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[n, {{1}, 0}, {40, All}]], {n, 0, 255, 1}]
```

[image]